# Detect first if file is existing before executing the program

Tags: python

How can I check if a file is existing, for example trend.log is existing therefore execute the program, otherwise loop again.

Here is my program, I want to execute if trendx.log is present in my path:

```
logtext = "trendx.log"
#Log data into dataframe using genfromtxt
logdata = np.genfromtxt(logtext + ".txt",invalid_raise = False,dtype=str, comments=None,usecols=np.arange(16))
logframe = pd.DataFrame(logdata)
#print (logframe.head())

#Dataframe trimmed to use only SHA1, PRG and IP
df2=(logframe[[10,11]]).rename(columns={10:'SHA-1', 11: 'DESC'})
#print (df2.head())

#sha1_vsdt data into dataframe using read_csv
df1=pd.read_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",delimiter=",",error_bad_lines=False,engine = 'python',quoting=3)
#Using merge to compare the two CSV

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='SHA-1', how='left').fillna('undetected')
df1['DESC'] = df['DESC'].values

df1.to_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use os.path.isfile to check if file exist. You can loop in a while loop till file doesn't exist and execute your code after that loop.

```
import os

logtext = "trendx.log"
while not os.path.isfile(logtext):
    pass


#Log data into dataframe using genfromtxt
logdata = np.genfromtxt(logtext + ".txt",invalid_raise = False,dtype=str, comments=None,usecols=np.arange(16))
logframe = pd.DataFrame(logdata)
#print (logframe.head())

#Dataframe trimmed to use only SHA1, PRG and IP
df2=(logframe[[10,11]]).rename(columns={10:'SHA-1', 11: 'DESC'})
#print (df2.head())

#sha1_vsdt data into dataframe using read_csv
df1=pd.read_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",delimiter=",",error_bad_lines=False,engine = 'python',quoting=3)
#Using merge to compare the two CSV

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='SHA-1', how='left').fillna('undetected')
df1['DESC'] = df['DESC'].values

df1.to_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: invalid syntax, but this is what im looking for, can your fix your answer so i can accept it

Comment: Ahh! There was a issue with using ! vs not. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
if os.path.isfile("trendx.log"):
    pass
    # File exists
else: 
    pass
    # File doesn't exist
```

Comment: Please some comments or description to explain how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `os.path` module?

```
from os import path
if path.exists(my_filepath):
    execute_my_program()
```

You can add a sleep:

```
from os import path
from time import sleep

def wait_and_process_file(filepath, wait_interval=5, max_time=3600):
    total_time = 0
    while total_time < max_time and not path.exists(filepath):
         sleep(wait_interval)
         total_time += wait_interval

    _finish_processing(filepath)
```